# What does 1 piece baggage mean?

Tags: luggage, alitalia

I booked my ticket from Alitalia. On the ticket it says 1 piece for baggage.

Does this mean I have 1 checked baggage and 1 hand-baggage?

Answer (score 11):

One piece refers to [checked luggage](https://www.alitalia.com/en_ca/fly-alitalia/baggage/checked-baggage.html). You will also be allowed a [carry on](https://www.alitalia.com/en_ca/fly-alitalia/baggage/hand-baggage.html) plus a personal item.